# Dynamicaly decoratoring methods in a class on Python

Tags: python, dynamic, decorator

I'm thinking about creating a decorator for a class, which can add a decorator dynamically to specific methods that start with a certain word, instead of manually adding the decorator to each method.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Below code example shows how to do that:

```
def class_dec(starts_with,fun_dec):
    def fun(cls):
        for k,v in cls.__dict__.items():
            if k.startswith(starts_with):
                cls.__dict__[k] = fun_dec(v)
        return cls
    return fun

def fun_decorator(f):
    def dec(*args,**kwargs):
        print "I m decorating"
        f(*args,**kwargs)
    return dec

@class_dec("name",fun_decorator)
class Hello:
    def name_new_one(self):
        print "new one"

    def name(self):
        print "Hello"

h = Hello()
h.name()
h.name_new_one()
```

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: 'dictproxy' object does not support item assignment

Which seems valid. Maybe instead of using a decorator, I can decorate methods, every time they are called? What python magic method is called before methods calls?